# How Can I put Date Picker in Gridview in edit mode ASP .Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, datepicker

I want to change the default text field in a gridview when in edit mode to a javascript date picker? How can I code it?

Code below (Gridview):

```
<asp:GridView id="grdViewEmpList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="5" allowpaging="true" Font-Size="11px" OnRowDataBound="grdViewEmpList_RowDataBound"
            GridLines="Both" ShowFooter="false" CssClass="gridview" CellPadding="4" Width="750px" OnRowEditing="grdViewEmpList_RowEditing"
            PagerSettings-Mode="Numeric" AllowSorting="true" autopostback="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnRowCancelingEdit="grdViewEmpList_RowCancelingEdit"
            EmptyDataText="No record found" OnRowCreated="grdViewEmpList_RowCreated" OnPageIndexChanging="grdViewEmpList_PageIndexChanging" OnRowUpdating="grdViewEmpList_RowUpdating">
        <RowStyle Wrap="true" ForeColor="#666666" BorderColor="#FFFFFF" BorderWidth="0" BackColor="#CCCCFF" CssClass="gridview_alter"/>
        <AlternatingRowStyle Wrap="true" ForeColor="#666666" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderWidth="0" BackColor="#FFFFFF" CssClass="gridview_alter"/>
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" EditText="Edit" UpdateText="Save" ButtonType="Image" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Action" EditImageUrl="~/Images/dotNet/pencil.png" CancelImageUrl="~/Images/dotNet/edit-not-validated-icon.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/Images/dotNet/edit-validated-icon.png"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EMP_ID" readonly="true" ItemStyle-Height="20px" HeaderText="Employee ID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="allWidth100" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" readonly="true" HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="allWidth460" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EFF_DATE" HeaderText="Effective Date" HeaderStyle-CssClass="allWidth100" DataFormatString="{0:d}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ControlStyle-CssClass="txtCommon allWidth80 txtCenter" />
        </Columns>
        <PagerSettings Mode="Numeric" PageButtonCount="5" Position="Bottom" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#FFCC33" HorizontalAlign="left" CssClass="gridview_pager"/>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code of the Date Picker in HTML which I want to put in above gridview in `EFF_DATE` column:

```
<input type="text" id="txtEffDate" name="txtEffDate" class="txtCommon allWidth80" value="" readonly="readonly" />
<img alt="Calendar" src="../Images/DateTimePickerImg/cal.gif" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript: NewCssCal('txtEffDate')" />
```

Comment: Both answer of **FlopScientist** and **Jumpei Tanaka** is correct. Using `<asp:TemplateField>` is the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `<asp:TemplateField>` in this case.

The `BoundField` is used by data-bound controls such as GridView to display the value of a field as text. So you can also use a Label for the same purpose when using TemplateField, [ i.e. when using Templates to define the layout of your Columns ]

So, change the Markup for your field: **`EFF_DATE`** from

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="EFF_DATE" HeaderText="Effective Date" 
      HeaderStyle-CssClass="allWidth100" DataFormatString="{0:d}" 
      ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
      ControlStyle-CssClass="txtCommon allWidth80 txtCenter" />
```

to this:

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lnl1" 
          Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EFF_DATE").ToString()%>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
          <input type="text" id="txtEffDate" name="txtEffDate" 
                 class="txtCommon allWidth80" value="" readonly="readonly" />
          <img alt="Calendar" src="../Images/spain.png" style="cursor: pointer;"
               onclick="javascript: NewCssCal('txtEffDate')" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Use TemplateField to add the datepicker in editmode. Add a custom class to the textbox,

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Effective Date" SortExpression="EFF_DATE" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEffDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EFF_DATE") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtEffDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EFF_DATE") %>'  CssClass="Datepicker"/>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

By using your gridview ID you can bind datepicker to your textbox.

```
$(function () {
        var $gv = $("table[id$=grdViewEmpList]");
        var $rows = $("> tbody > tr:not(:has(th, table))", $gv);
        var $inputs = $(".Datepicker", $rows);
        $inputs.datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a date picker to use `TemplateField` like below.

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Effective Date" 
                SortExpression="EFF_DATE" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEffDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EFF_DATE") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtEffDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EFF_DATE") %>' />
                    <img alt="Calendar" src="../Images/DateTimePickerImg/cal.gif" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript: NewCssCal('txtEffDate')" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```